# SqlProfileProvider

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I am trying to get SqlProfileProvider working with my own db, I have set up the db using aspnet_regsql and then the following web.config, yet the application keeps creating an aspnetdb and never populates any of the tables in my db.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Database"
       connectionString="Server=MYSERVER;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=MYDB"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
<providers>
  <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
       type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
             System.Web, Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"   
         type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
         connectionStringName="Database"
         applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false" />
```

Comment: Does the "Database" connectionstring actually point to your database instance? Does the account you use to connect to the database have rights on more than one schema/db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `<clear />` tag immediately after the `<connectionStrings>` tag.  I seem to remember having a similar problem years ago that was caused by my web.config inheriting a connection string from somewhere else.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayb15wz8.aspx

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="Database"
       connectionString="Server=MYSERVER;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=MYDB"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

EDIT:

Actually, you should also add the `<clear />` tag to your membership providers as well.

[Common Gotcha: Don't forget to `<clear/>` when adding providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/20/common-gotcha-don-t-forget-to-clear-when-adding-providers.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, you are exactly right, I found this myself before I logged back into StackOverflow... it was because machine.config had default connections that were causing issues.  Some well placed <clear />'s fixed that